# Remove tag synonym [xp] -> [windows-xp]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms

I just find a question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875370/book-comparing-of-agile-methodologies, where [xp](/questions/tagged/xp) is synonym to [windows-xp](/questions/tagged/windows-xp), which obviously doesn't make sense. XP can be used to describe Windows XP but it can also be used to describe Extreme programming. The mentioned question is off topic but it doesn't mean it should be automatically wrongly retagged.

Comment: Agreed, that question deserves to be on another site geared for people who want to look up dewey numbers

Comment: Seems to me, the OP should have noticed that his question was tagged "windows-xp" and revised his question.  The "extreme-programming" tag came up straight away, when I started typing "extreme".

Answer (score 4):

I think that in most the cases, when somebody hears *XP* thinks to Windows XP, rather than to extreme programming.

The fact the question is using [xp](/questions/tagged/xp) to mean *extreme programming* or *Windows XP* is not, I think, the reason the question has been voted to be closed, especially from who voted to close it as off-topic: The reason is that the question has been (probably) seen as a buying recommendation. The other problem I could see with the question is that there could be another book published right after the book somebody could suggest, and the answer would not be valid anymore after a new book has been published. (With this I mean that who suggested a book could change idea once a new book is published.) Also, every answer would be equally valid, and asking questions where every answer would be equally valid is something the FAQ suggest not to do.

As for which synonyms to use for a tag, that is something normally decided by the community; a moderator can directly create synonym tags, but the community can still express an opinion about the opportunity of using a synonym. You can report here when you think a synonym should not be used for a tag. The votes for your question give an indication of what other users think about using the synonym: Who down-votes your question is against removing the synonym; who up-votes your question agrees with you that the synonym should not be used for that tag, or not used at all.
If you have enough score for a tag, you can vote any synonym tags, or suggest a new synonym. If you don't have enough score, you can propose a synonym tag on the meta site, and users will vote for your question.

Comment: Yes, but this is the place to let it be known if you disagree with synonym.  There's no other way.

Comment: @LanceRoberts: True. And  I think the downvotes on your question indicate that people generally AGREE with the synonym.

Comment: Of course, somebody could disagree with the used synonym. I was just pointing out that if the synonym is used, then probably it has been decided from the community. I hope my answer doesn't sound as saying that nobody can report a synonym that they think should not be used, because it's not what I meant.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, actually mods can make a synonym happen, so we don't really know if it was a community vote or not.

Comment: That is true, but in this case the synonym is reported to be created by skaffman, on October. If skaffman was not a moderator in October, then it was not created by a moderator. It's true that moderators can create synonyms, though; as I have been a moderator, and created synonym tags, I can witness it is possible.

Comment: I don't discuss reason for closing the question and I don't agree with your opinion. Questions about books are not off topic. After a new book is released anybody can still add a new answer and track list of valuable resources. There are plenty of questions about books on SO.

Comment: It depends on who reads the question, and how reads it. It is more probable it has been closed as off-topic because it has been interpreted as buying recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

The majority of people will think of Windows, when they see 'XP'. If this tag synonym were to be removed or changed to mean *extreme programming*, it would cause a lot of questions to be mis-tagged by people who followed their first instincts.

If a tag is needed for *extreme programming*, it should be something else.

Comment: There already was [a tag for extreme programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/extreme-programming).

Comment: Actually the guy who use tag XP to mean Windows-XP is not able to ask correct question. If any relevant article talks about Windows XP it uses full name not only XP which is not true for extreme programming where XP is general acronym. The confusion is there anyway and lifetime of Windows-XP is almost at its end whereas Extreme-programming is still here. XP without Windows doesn't mean Windows-XP.